# Attaching onDelete event handler in a content control in word using OfficeJS

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I have content control in word. Now I want a certain action to take place whenever that particular content control is deleted. After some googling, I found that there is an event called [onDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=word-js-preview#onDeleted) which can be used for the same. However, I am quite not able to understand how to attach this event handler. Can someone give an example of a code on how we can attach this listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handling in Word is the same as event handling in Excel. For example, you attach a handler to the worksheet.onChanged event like this:

```
Excel.run(function (context) {
  var worksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
  worksheet.onChanged.add(handleChange);

  return context.sync()
      .then(function () {
          console.log("Event handler successfully registered for onChanged event in the worksheet.");
      });
}).catch(errorHandlerFunction);
```

So too, in Word, you get a reference to the content control and add a handler to the ContentControl.onDeleted event like this:

```
Word.run(function (context) {
  var myContentControl = context.document.contentControls.getFirst();
  myContentControl.onDeleted.add(handleDeletion);

  return context.sync()
      .then(function () {
          console.log("Event handler successfully registered for onDeleted event in the document.");
      });
}).catch(errorHandlerFunction);
```

You also remove handlers in Word events just as they are removed in Excel. For details, see [Excel add-in events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-events).

Comment: Thanks @Rick for the explanation. However, I am facing an issue.
Using the below code, I create a content control;
const range = context.document.body.insertOoxml(ooxml, Word.InsertLocation.end);
      const contentControl = range.insertContentControl();
      contentControl.title = templateIdentifier;
      contentControl.cannotEdit = true;
      contentControl.onDeleted.add(handleDeletion);

However, I get the following error.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
Can you explain what might be the reason for this.

Comment: onDeleted is still in preview. You have to use the preview version of Office JS. See [Accessing Office JS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office#accessing-the-office-javascript-api-library) and [Referencing the the JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/referencing-the-javascript-api-for-office-library-from-its-cdn).

Comment: Thanks, @Rick, and apologies for the late reply. It helped me. 
However, I am still facing an error that is related to office-js. Particularly related to custom XML. Could you please explain that thing also if it's possible? I will post a link in the comment or another question for that if required.

Comment: This sounds like a new problem, so you should create a new question in stack, and mark this one as answered.

Comment: I have created a new question regarding the same. Thanks for the help on this issue. :)